# Mobile devices (iPhone, iPad) aren't showing the correct CSS for a button

Tags: html, css, forms

I am working on a website and can't seem to figure out why this button doesn't look right on mobile

The public website is, http://www.cinirgy.com

[Mobile View - Submit button is defaultish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsi1C.png)

[Desktop - Submit button is how it should be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDdmG.jpg)

Here is my code for the button….

```
 .submit input {  
width: auto;  
padding: 9px 15px;  
background: #fff;  
border: 0;  
font-size: 14px;  
color: #FFFFFF;  
-moz-border-radius: 10px;  
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;  
}
```

All help is very much obliged :D

Comment: Have you tried background-image:none;? And maybe -webkit-appearance: none; before any other webkit options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `-webkit-appearance: none;` before any other webkit specific settings, [this article may be of help](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safaricssref/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-_webkit_appearance), also [here from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/-moz-appearance)

> The appearance CSS property is used to display an element using a
>   platform-native styling based on the operating system's theme.